# How can I get this balloon present?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

So I was minding my own business on the island and noticed this balloon floating by:

[image: a present tied to a balloon floating by my tent]

I don't know where it came from, but that's really not the issue. What I want to know is how am I supposed to get a balloon present down to the ground? I tried swinging at it with my net, but that didn't work, and now it's floated across the river. How can I get at one of these next time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should shoot them down with a slingshot ([Fandom](https://animalcrossing.fandom.com/wiki/Present)):

> Presents can also appear attached to balloons and must (...) shot with a slingshot.

Do note though, as further down it states:

> If shot down over water or flowers, the present will be destroyed and the player will become shocked by it. The present can also be destroyed if it lands in the center of a 3x3 pattern layout.

[Fandom](https://acnl.fandom.com/wiki/Balloon_Presents) also has a nice tutorial/strategy in case you do not have a slingshot:

> If the player does not have a slingshot, there's still a way to knock the presents down from balloons. First the player should find a balloon. If it's drifting towards a cliff (depending on the layout of the town, there will be a cliff to the east or the west) he/she is in luck. Wait for the balloon to reach the cliff.
>
> As it passes the cliff, the balloon will lower. The player should get within range of it with a net or shovel out, and use the net or shovel as if he/she was hitting a villager. The balloon should pop, and the present will drop to the beach below. If the player misses, he/she will have a moment or two to try again.
>
> This strategy will not always work, as the balloon may be heading in the direction away from the cliff. If so, the player will have to wait and try again with a balloon heading the other way.

Comment: An addendum to your note about presents being destroyed: landing on trees or placed items can make the present just vanish, as if it had never been. There's no look of shock like when it falls into water. I think it's a bug, but I can't be sure.

Comment: @Yamikuronue that isn’t a bug per se. In previous games, if you had too many fruits lying around a tree and you shook it again for more fruit, the new ones would disappear. Speculation here: the character’s reaction to the present landing in the river likely serves to tell the player they can’t get it back. The developers may not have coded anything for losing items due to clutter since the player may more quickly realize that they aren’t getting it back. The player will also more naturally have an immediate reaction to the loss.